# blazor OnAfterRenderAsync

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

i have a blazor page which has a MailLayout
on my layout i have to component HomeMenu and Footer like this

```
div class="page" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".privacy-nav">
    <div>
        <HomeMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body

        </article>

    </main>
    <div>
        <Footer />
    </div>

</div>
```

in my HomeMenu component i want to add Active css class base on selection of each menu

```
<nav class="navbar main-nav navbar-expand-lg px-2 px-sm-0 py-2 py-lg-0">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img style="width:30px;height:30px" src="images/masjedalkufa_b.png" alt="logo">Masjed AlKufa</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="ti-menu"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-sm-auto">
                <li class="nav-item @@home @Active("/")">
                    <a class="nav-link"  href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item @@termofuse ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/TermsOfUse">Terms Of Use</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item @@about">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/About-Us">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item @@contact @Active("/contact-us")">
                    <a class="nav-link"  href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="/login">
            <img src="images/masjedalkufa_b.png" width="30" /> Sign In
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

```
and my code is like this 

@code {

    private string Active(string st)
    {
        int len = MyNavigationManager.Uri.Length;
        int start = IndexOfOccurence(MyNavigationManager.Uri, "/", 3);
        string Current = MyNavigationManager.Uri.Substring(start, len - start);

        if (st == Current.ToLower())
        {
            return "active";
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private int IndexOfOccurence(string s, string match, int occurence)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int cnt = 0;

        while (i <= s.Length)
        {
            var st = s.IndexOf(match, index);
            if (st > 0)
            {
                cnt++;
                if (cnt == occurence)
                {
                    return st;
                }

                index = st + 1;
            }

            i++;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

but this code only run once when project start and when i click on other menu the active class wont change

i tried this

```
  protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        StateHasChanged();
        return null;
    }
```

and ended up getting this following error

blazor.webassembly.js:1  crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.NotifyRenderCompleted(ComponentState state, List`1& batch) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InvokeRenderCompletedCalls(ArrayRange`1 updatedComponents, Task updateDisplayTask)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()

what can i do to achieve such a thing ?

i tried many many different code but no lock

Comment: Are you trying to emulate the `NavLink` component? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#navlink-and-navmenu-components  If so what's wrong with it?   Here's a link to the soure code if you want to modify it. - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Components/Web/src/Routing

Answer (score 2):

The below code is likely your current problem for that error. You cannot return null when Blazor is expecting a Task, return Task.CompletedTask instead. Also, you are telling Blazor to re-render after every time it renders which causes a never ending loop. If you want it to re-render once after the first render check for firstRender and then call StateHasChanged() if true. (This doesn't solve your actual goal, see next section for that.)

Change:

```cs
  protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        StateHasChanged();
        return null;
    }
```

To:

```cs
  protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
       if (firstRender){
           StateHasChanged();
       }
       return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Now for the main goal of your post...

You can tell your Layout StateHasChanged on a navigation event. From [Detecting navigation events](https://blazor-university.com/routing/detecting-navigation-events/)

```cs
        [Inject]
        NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

        void LocationChanged(object? sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string navigationMethod = e.IsNavigationIntercepted ? "HTML" : "code";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Notified of navigation via {navigationMethod} to {e.Location}");

            StateHasChanged();
        }

        // make sure your Component implements IDisposable
        public void Dispose()
        {
            NavigationManager.LocationChanged -= LocationChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            // Subscribe to the event
            NavigationManager.LocationChanged += LocationChanged;
            base.OnInitialized();

        }
```

This will allow your Layout the ability to re-run your Active detection method when the URL changes.

Comment: that's an interesting idea, let me check it and i'll let you know

Answer (score 1):

Your component does not have any knowledge of when the URL is changed. You can subscribe to the `NavigationManager.LocationChanged` event to notify the component of URL changes.

Since this is not a Blazor event you need call `StateHasChanged()` in the subscribing method e.g. `HandleLocationChanged`.

And to prevent memory leaks we need to unsubscribe from the `LocationChanged` event. This can be done by implementing the `IDisposable` interface and using the `Dispose` method that it exposes.

Here's an article for [Detecting navigation events](https://blazor-university.com/routing/detecting-navigation-events/) in blazor.

```cs
@implements IDisposable
@inject NavigationManager MyNavigationManager

//...

@code {
    private string _currentUri;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _currentUri = MyNavigationManager.Uri;
        MyNavigationManager.LocationChanged += HandleLocationChanged;
    }

    private void HandleLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _currentUri = e.Location;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private string Active(string route)
    {
        return _currentUri.EndsWith(route) ? "active" : "";
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        MyNavigationManager.LocationChanged -= HandleLocationChanged;
    }
}
```

Finally, do **NOT** do this.

```cs
protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    StateHasChanged();
    return null;
}
```

Calling `StateHasChanged()` inside the `OnAfterRenderAsync` method can lead to an infinite render loop. And you cant return a `null` when the expected return type is a `Task`.

Comment: thanks for your reply , i'll try this and let you know